# Get current logged user in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have a web part that shows me a survey. I need to get the current user so that I can hide or show certain information for the survey depending on the current user's permissions.

Answer (score 9):

`SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser` should do the trick.  It has functions like `IsSiteAdmin` and `Groups` that you should be able to use.