# Retrieving Current Sharepoint User in aspx.cs Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created a web application which is loaded in Sharepoint 2010. I created the web parts in Visual Studio 2010 using aspx and aspx.cs. The forms are used to get data which is them loaded into a Microsoft Server Database.

I want to retrieve the user who is logged into Sharepoint to load in the database as the person who created the record. Can anyone guide me on how this can be done?

Comment: How about usual `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current logged user in Sharepoint 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089400/get-current-logged-user-in-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sharepoint designer you can do this as described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2008/06/03/getting-the-current-user-name-or-id-in-sharepoint-using-sharepoint-designer-no-code.aspx